# squeryl date to long conversion - query hangs on simple operation

Tags: date, playframework-2.0, long-integer, squeryl

kind of a follow up question to my previous one: 
[squeryl date to long conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407269/squeryl-date-to-long-conversion)

I implemented a DateTime(model) to Long(DB) conversion as mentioned in that thread.
I wrote a simple query to delete all records with an expired date:

```
println("deleting expired")
val now: DateTime = new DateTime()
inTransaction {
  MyDB.loginTokens.deleteWhere(t =>
    t.expires lt now.getMillis
  )
}
println("finished deleting")
```

but the query just hangs in there and does nothing, no error is thrown...
I only see "deleting expired" printed and never "finished".
I also tried "t.expires lt now" and some other variants without success.

any idea what's causing this and how to fix it?

EDIT
when changing lt to .~ <, there is still a problem
when changing lt to === the query works fine both with now and now.getMillis.

Comment: I think its a bug. all the operations except lt/< work...

Answer (score 0):

t.expires.~ lt now

Notice the dot tilda.
Not sure why "lt" by itself doesn't work, like === works.
perhaps its a synonym to something else...